# Java type capture for inner classes

Tags: java, types

I have the following (obviously useless in this form) Java class:

```
public class EntrySet<T> {

    public static class Entry<T> {
        T obj;
    }

    private final Set<Entry<T>> set;

    public EntrySet() {
        this.set = Sets.newHashSet();
    }

    public Set<Entry<T>> getEntries() {
        return set;
    }
}
```

Given this class, the following does not compile:

```
EntrySet<?> entrySet = new EntrySet<SomeClass>();
Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>> entries = entrySet.getEntries();
```

The second line has the compile error "cannot convert from `Set<EntrySet.Entry<capture#1-of ?>>` to `Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>>`". I cannot find a way to eliminate this error, even with casting or using a helper function.

What exactly is the issue here, and is there a way to get a clean compile?

The best I could do is:

```
EntrySet<?> entrySet = new EntrySet<SomeClass>();
Set<?> tmp = entrySet.getEntries();
Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>> entries = (Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>>) tmp;
```

which is obviously terrible (even with the relevant warning suppression).

Comment: Did you try EntrySet<SomeClass> entrySet = new EntrySet<SomeClass>(); ?

Comment: This is just some dummy code to keep the issue clear. That of course would work, but in my case all I have is an `EntrySet<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `entrySet` you are attempting to assign a `Set<EntrySet.Entry<SomeClass>>` to `Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>>`. There are hundreds of Stack Overflow questions which are essentially the same thing. You could add a `EntrySet.Entry<OtherClass>` to the latter but not the former, so that would break type-safety.

Probably the way to deal with this is to capture the wild card by calling a method with a (named) generic parameter.

```
    EntrySet<?> entrySet = new EntrySet<SomeClass>();
    fn(entrySet);
...
private static <T> void fn(EntrySet<T> entrySet) {
    Set<EntrySet.Entry<T>> entries = entrySet.getEntries();
```

Comment: You cannot add `EntrySet.Entry<OtherClass>` to `Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>>`. You cannot add *anything* to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the problem. As @MiserableVariable says, you can't insert into a `Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>>`. For example, it's totally OK to write `Map<?, ?> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` followed by `Set<?> keys = map.keySet();`. There's something about the fact the wildcard is nested that's different, and while it's certainly something like you're saying, I don't see it.

Comment: I believe you can add to `Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>>` (not got Java installed on this machine to check). / I guess declaring `entries` as `Set<? extends EntrySet.Entry<?>>` would also work (for some ends).

Comment: A `Set<? extends Foo>` is a set of of some **unknown type** that extends `Foo`. If `Bar extends Foo` and `Baz extends Foo` then  `Set<Foo>`, `Set<Baz>` and `Set<Bar>` can all be assigned to a variable whose static type is `Set<? extends Foo>`. You cannot **add** anything to it because anything you can add would break contract for two of the above three. I am sure There are hundreds of Stack Overflow questions which are essentially the same thing :)

Comment: @MiserableVariable But we were not talking about `Set<? extends Foo>`. We were talking about `Set<Foo<?>>`, which is an entirely different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

The unbounded wild card `<?>` is like the super-type of all generic types. It is similar to what an Object class is to all java classes. The only operations that you can perform on a unbounded wildcard reference are those which take a 'null' (if `<?>` parameter is used in the argument reference) or those that return a 'Object' (if `<?>` parameter is used in the return type reference). So your code will compile if it returns a reference of the type Object.

```
 class EntrySet<T> {

    public static class Entry<T> {
        T obj;
    }

    private final java.util.Set<Entry<T>> set;

    public EntrySet() {
        this.set = new java.util.HashSet();
    }

    public java.util.Set<Entry<T>> getEntries() {
        return set;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        EntrySet<?> entrySet = new EntrySet<SomeClass>();

    //java.util.Set<EntrySet.Entry<?>> entries = entrySet.getEntries(); // Error

         Object o = entrySet.getEntries();         // OK !
    }
}

class SomeClass{}
```